# awaiting a void function in typescript

Tags: angular, observable

I'm new to TypeScript. I sort of understand Observables and waiting for them `subscribe()` or `pipe()`. But I don't understand quite why below code does not work. For clarity, the `refresh()` function at the bottom needs to:

1. Update available Locations from the server;
2. Run a health check against each of those locations.

   ```
   getLocations(): Observable<void> {
       this.locations = [];

       this.healthCheckService.getLocations() // service returns an Observable
               .subscribe(location_names => (
                       location_names.forEach((location_name) => {
                           this.locations.push(new Location({'name': location_name}))
                       })
               ));
   }

   getHealth(location): void {
       this.healthCheckService.getHealth(location)
           .subscribe(health => (
               location.health = health,
               this.isLoaded = true
           ));
   }

   refresh(): void {
       this.getLocations().subscribe(_ => {
           this.locations.forEach((location) => {
               this.getHealth(location);
           })
       });
   }
   ```

   }

I understand that I have to return an Observable from the `getLocations()` function in order for it to be subscribable. But since `getLocations()` itself needs to await a result, I imagine I need to return this Observable in the subscribe function. However that's syntactically not OK.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The return type of `getLocations` function is observable. But you are not returning any observable in it. You do not have return statements inside that function.

```
getLocations(): Observable<void> {
  this.locations = [];

  return this.healthCheckService.getLocations()
    .do(location_names => (
       location_names.forEach((location_name) => {
       this.locations.push(new Location({'name': location_name}))
     }));  //assuming this function returns observable
}
```

You can use `rxjs` `do/tap` operator to make changes to your `this.location[]` variable.

This way you will be returning an observable and your refresh function will be able to subscribe to it.

Comment: I could do that, but then my `this.locations[]` array isn't being set by `getLocations()`.

Comment: you can set this.locations[] inside your refresh function as well.

Comment: correct, but then I'd be repeating code, which goes against the reusability principle.

Comment: You can use rxjs `do/tap` operator to make the changes to this.location[]

Comment: that indeed works! Thank you :) If you add this to your answer I can accept it.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/169031/discussion-between-bluppfisk-and-ashfaq-p).

Answer (score 2):

You can use the `.do` function instead of subscribe.

Then, in the refresh, you can use `Observable.forkJoin` to wait for all of the `getHealth` observables to finish

```ts
getLocations(): Observable<void> {
    this.locations = [];

    return this.healthCheckService.getLocations()
        .do(location_names => (
                location_names.forEach((location_name) => {
                    this.locations.push(new Location({'name': location_name}))
                })
        ));
}

getHealth(location): void {
    return this.healthCheckService.getHealth(location)
        .do(health => (
            location.health = health,
            this.isLoaded = true
        ));
}

refresh(): void {
    return this.getLocations().flatMap(_ => {
        return Observable.forkJoin(this.locations.map((location) => {
            return this.getHealth(location);
        }));
    });
}
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer, and sorry, I should have probably mentioned that `healthCheckService.getLocations()` itself returns an `Observable<Location[]>`, on which the `do()` function is not available.

Comment: You could try and change it to something like `.tap`